# JavaScript ECMA 6 project

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6

I would like to set up a JavaScript ECMA 6 project. But I'm insecure about the general approach.

I've set up a project with Jasmine 2.5.3 and Karma 1.5 (and Chutzpah) but it seems that they don't support ECMA 6. (Arrow functions are not working for example)

Did I miss something - do Jasmine and Karma support EMCA 6? Or do I first have to compile ECMA 6 code (with babel) into ECMA 5 code?

Regards

Comment: Yes, you need babel to transpile the ES6 to ES5

Answer (score 0):

You would **add a preprocessing step to your test setup which takes care of transpiling the ES6 code to ES5**. Babel is one popular option you could use for that.

See [this article](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/writing-jasmine-unit-tests-in-es6) outlining the general approach:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        files: [
            { pattern: 'test-context.js', watched: false }
        ],
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        preprocessors: {
            'test-context.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: {
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    { test: /\.js/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
                ]
            },
            watch: true
        },
        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought so. But Jasmine and Karma are so famous and so is EMCA 6. According to http://stateofjs.com/2016/flavors/ 74% are using ECMA 6. Why isn't Jasmine, Karma etc. not supporting ECMA 6?

Comment: Well, [Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/tree/master/src/core) itself is also just another JavaScript library. It is the runtime environment that you use to execute the test cases that does or doesn't support ES6, not Jasmine. This will likely be Node.js. [Node.js does support some ES6 features, but not all of them.](http://node.green/) Transpiling ES6 is really a perfectly normal step in front-end development these days.